# How to add checkmark to TableViewController from other ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have a TableViewController, when certain cell pressed it goes to my DetailViewController to display more details about the pressed cell.

On this DetailViewController, I would like to add a `button` and when this `button` gets pressed a "CHECKMARK" will add to its cell from TableViewController and goes back to TableViewController. How would you do that?

I already added an IBAction for my button but I don't know how I would implement that yet..

*Please speak in layman's term as much as possible because I'm not that yet very familiar with iOS Programming. Thank you so much.*

Comment: You can use `protocol` mechanism to inform the delegate class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `protocol` for message transfer.

In your `detailViewController` create protocol,

```
@protocol yourDetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)yourDetailViewController:(YourDetailViewController *)controller didSelectObject:(YourObject *)object;

@end
```

and create `delegate` object,

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<yourDetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Then in your tableViewController implement the delegate method,

```
- (void)yourDetailViewController:(YourDetailViewController *)controller didSelectObject:(YourObject *)object {

  // code for add check mark

}
```

In your button action,

```
- (void)buttonAction {
  // Call the delegate method
  [delegate yourDetailViewController:self didSelectObject:changedObject];

}
```

Comment: Hi @Anusha, where will you apply this `protocol` ? Don't know yet how to use it.

Comment: @Rhenzzz I have added the basic things here. You can get the detailed answers in stackoverflow itself. Please search that..

Comment: Thanks @Anusha, I will try this out. :) Thank you very much. Hope this works for my app.